# How to find out a linux kernel ring buffer size?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

Quite interested in the size of the kernel ring buffer, how much information it can hold, and what data types?

Comment: On some embedded boxes it might differ.  In my system, it's kept under /VERSION.gz and can be queried as 

`zgrep LOG_BUF_SHIFT /VERION.gz`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regarding the size, it's recorded in your kernel's config file.  For example, on Amazon EC2 here, it's 256 [KiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte).

```
# grep CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT=18
# perl -e 'printf "%d KiB\n",(1<<18)/1024'
256 KiB
#
```

Referenced in [/kernel/printk/printk.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/printk/printk.c)

```
#define __LOG_BUF_LEN (1 << CONFIG_LOG_BUF_SHIFT)
```

More information in [/kernel/trace/ring_buffer.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/trace/ring_buffer.c)

Note that if you've passed a kernel boot param "log_buf_len=N" (check using `cat /proc/cmdline`) then that [overrides](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks) the value in the config file.