# Storing Huge Data in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tcp, dmesg

I have a customized Linux Kernel which prints to dmesg and syslog (using printk) some additional information about each received MP-TCP packet in the system. Things work perfectly, however I am generating a huge amount of data (using `iperf` tool) around 2 Gbps of data which correspond to extremely high number of packets. Because of the printk, all my CPUs are 100% loaded in my system (I have 4 CPUs). I am worried that this might affect the packet processing in my system and causes additional problems and latyency. So my question is there any alternative method for storing my data in the Liunx Kernel without increasing the load on my CPUs?

To give an example of the size of the data, for 60 seconds of an iperf session, the size of the `/var/log/syslog is around 1.2 Gbytes.

Let me add one more thing, I do not need to process the reported data by the Linux Kernel in an online fashion. I will process them in offline mode.

Comment: `printk` prints to the kernel ring buffer, which is usually highly limited. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332422/how-to-find-out-a-linux-kernel-ring-buffer-size
If your system is additionally configured to log to `/var/log/syslog`, wich is usually an ordinary file, probably the file open and write operations will cause a huge I/O load on your system.

Comment: Yes, I am already aware about the limitation of kernel ring buffer. I have already increased it to 16 MBytes which is the maximum value but it is still small. This is why I am using `/var/log/syslog` to check my data. But as you said and I reported in my question it causes huge I/O. So do you have any alternative solution?

Comment: A faster solution might be storing it in RAM i.e. a sufficiently large `tmpfs`.

Comment: Any good example?

Comment: Just mount a `tmpfs` in some directory where you'd like to log your stuff. You *can* even mount it to /var/log.
E.g. `mount -t tmpfs -o size=4G tmpfs /var/log`
But be reminded that you'll need sufficient RAM and that using SWAP might slow down your system again.

Comment: Well, since I did multiple measurement and each measurement results in 1.2 GBytes of file size. I think I am in safe. But what you provided will be done from the user space. So in the Kernel space how do you I log my data to that temporary file?

Comment: You're currently using syslog(d) to log stuff to `/var/log/syslog` if I understand correctly. So you're already using a user space program for logging. I am not familiar with kernel-mode logging besides printing to the kernel ring buffer and am quite certain that a kernel is not meant to do this kind of logging at all. It's meant to do low-level hardware abstraction in software, not logging huge data sets.

Comment: The Kernel when using printk function it write to dmesg which gets dumped to the syslog file. I am not sure how this is done. From my side, I am reading the syslog after I finished my `iperf` session for post-processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably look into **ftrace**, the built-in Linux kernel tracing tool. For example, this slightly out-of-date [LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/365835/) says

> Ftrace introduces a new form of printk() called **trace_printk()**. It can be used just like printk(), and can also be used in any context (interrupt code, NMI code, and scheduler code). What is nice about [trace_printk()](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L607) is that it does not output to the console. Instead it writes to the Ftrace ring buffer and can be read via the trace file. Writing into the ring buffer with trace_printk() only takes around a tenth of a microsecond or so.
>
> For example you can add something like this to the kernel or module:
>
> ```
> trace_printk("read foo %d out of bar %p\n", bar->foo, bar);
> ```

The [kernel doc ftrace.txt](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.13/source/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) has the details. In directory `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/` you can set the trace ring buffer size in pseudo-file `buffer_size_kb`.